# Hibernate Search upgrade for JDK-17 and Jakarta Persistence APIs

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

We are experimenting with JDK-17 migration. One of the steps was to migrate from javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence libraries.

Looks like Hibernate search is yet to upgrade to Jakarta Persistence. Could you please share if this is planned in future releases. or any alternatives.

Please be informed that we have tried with both  6.1.8.Final & 6.2.0.Alpha1 versions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Search 6.1+ does work with Jakarta Persistence and/or Hibernate ORM 6, but you have to switch to different Maven artifacts:

- Artifacts suffixed with `-orm6` for Hibernate ORM 6: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#other-integrations-orm6
- Artifacts suffixed with `-jakarta` for Hibernate ORM 5's `-jakarta` artifacts: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#other-integrations-jakarta

See also https://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix

Hibernate Search 7+ will use Hibernate ORM 6+ out of the box, in the main artifacts (no `-orm6` suffix needed).